# Highlight a cell with certain criteria

Tags: excel

Is it possible to highlight a cell, let's say red, with certain criteria. One could be SUM function returns a minus output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is conditional formatting.
[Here's a quick tutorial.](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/how_to_use_conditional_formatting_to_highlight_data)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something as simple as formatting negative numbers, the number formatting under  Format Cells allows this. You can also use custom formats for more complex or personalized formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom Format mask like:

```
[Green]0.00_;[Red]-0.00
```

If you want to highlight the cell rathe rthan the value, then use conditional formatting (as JNK has suggested)